# TypeError: Cannot read property 'file' of undefined, while updating Django model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, axios, multipartform-data, form-data

I update my model with axios and file field causes some error. I use PATCH method for updating and this means i can include only one field to change. For example when i only post new picture, my image field will be updated and i can leave other fields empty. So updating only my image fields works. But now when i try to update only my name field, next error occurs.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'file' of undefined

And next thing is that when i update my image field and name field at the same time, this also works and my model gets updated. This is really confusing error but i hope someone knows what could cause issue here. Thanks in advance!

My form handling method:

```
 handleFormSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        let form_data = new FormData();
        form_data.append('name', event.target.elements.name.value);
        form_data.append('email', event.target.elements.email.value);
        form_data.append('location', event.target.elements.location.value);
        form_data.append('sport', this.state.sport);
        form_data.append('image', this.state.file.file, this.state.file.file.name);
        console.log(form_data.image);
        const profileID = this.props.token
        let url = `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/profile/${profileID}/update`
        axios.patch(url, form_data, {
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
            }
        })
            .then(res => console.log(res))
            .catch(error => console.err(error));
        }
```

In the frontend i also use ReactJS and for Form, Ant Design Form, but it shouldn't matter

File object in my console:
[screenshot of console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APnHT.png)

DRF:

```
class ProfileViewUpdate(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
    lookup_field = 'token'
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'pk'
```

Serializer:

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('token', 'bio', 'name', 'email', 'sport', 'location', 'image')
```

console.log(this.state.file.file.name)
[filestate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tylsc.png)

I also tried updating with JSON data, but it didn't work as well:

```
handleFormSubmit = (event) => {
    const name = event.target.elements.name.value;
    const email = event.target.elements.email.value;
    const location  = event.target.elements.name.value;
    const sport = this.state.sport;
    const image = this.state.file.file;
    axios.defaults.headers = {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                Authorization: this.props.token
            }
    const profileID = this.props.token
    axios.patch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/profile/${profileID}/update`, {
        name: name,
        email: email,
        location: location,
        sport: sport,
        image: image,
    })
    .then(res => console.log(res))
    .catch(error => console.err(error));
 }
```

Comment: If formData is sent from the client, then you need to add the parser_classes, `parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)` in your view.

Comment: Okay, how do i define those? NameError: name 'MultiPartParser' is not defined

Comment: Ok got it, from rest_framework.parsers import MultiPartParser, FormParser

Comment: But somehow 'file' of undefined still occurs

Comment: can you share the `ProfileSerializer ` code

Comment: Yes, updated my post

Comment: I still think you should update the file state with index, like this - `form_data.append('image', this.state.file[0], this.state.file[0].name);`

Comment: then it shows error TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined, because as you can see in my console, file is one object not array

Comment: The screenshot you have shared is for `this.state.file`, right?

Comment: It shows what i have saved in my state as file, yes

Comment: It is so strange, like i said just updating image this way works, but when i try to update just name for example, it throws error

Comment: I think the filename is this - `this.state.file.name`. can you try

Comment: unfortunately error is still there

Comment: @Ejaz Have any other idea, what could be wrong?

Comment: Can you show how you are updating the file state in react? We can check that once.

Comment: and have you checked `console.log(this.state.file.file.name)`, is it logging filename?

Comment: I updated my post, you can see this.state.file.file.name has proper value. I am updating my state with setState and it should work. Because i can see my updated file in my state.

Comment: In the `url`, are you passing the `id` or `pk`? Its not there in the url above. And in the `Profile` model, what is the `image` field type? Do you have an `upload_to` path?

Comment: @Ejaz I updated my post and you can see that i tried to update my model with also JSON data. Unfortunately this gies also 400 Bad request error